# What is wrong with strncpy_s() here?

Tags: c++, strncpy

I am reading a textbook and trying to solve the question given to readers.

The fallowing code is function definition from my source file of my answer.

I want to copy content of character strings to another ones.

I chose functions strncpy_s().

But it does not work.

Microsoft Visual Studio says Debug Assertion Failed!

I have no idea how to fix it.

> cow.h

// class declarations

```
#include <iostream>
#ifndef COW_H_
#define COW_H_

class Cow {
char name[20];
char * hobby;
double weight;
public:
Cow();
Cow(const char * nm, const char * ho, double wt);
Cow(const Cow & c);
~Cow();
Cow & operator=(const Cow & c);
void ShowCow() const;  // display all cow data   
}; 
#endif
```

> cow.cpp

// class methods

```
Cow::Cow(const char * nm, const char * ho, double wt)
{
    int len = std::strlen(nm);
    strncpy_s(name, len, nm, len);
    name[19] = '\0';

    len = std::strlen(ho);
    hobby = new char[len + 1];
    strncpy_s(hobby, len, ho, len);
    hobby[len] = '\0';

    weight = wt;
}

Cow::Cow()
{
    strncpy_s(name, 19, "no name", 19);
    name[19] = '\0';

    int len = std::strlen("no hobby");
    hobby = new char[len + 1];
    strncpy_s(hobby, len, "no hobby", len);
    hobby[len] = '\0';

    weight = 0.0;
}

Cow::Cow(const Cow & c)
{
    int len = std::strlen(c.name);
    strncpy_s(name, len, c.name, len);
    name[19] = '\0';

    len = std::strlen(c.hobby);
    hobby = new char[len + 1];
    strncpy_s(hobby, len, c.hobby, len);
    hobby[len] = '\0';

    weight = c.weight;
}

Cow::~Cow()
{
    delete [] hobby;
}

Cow & Cow::operator=(const Cow & c)
{
    if (this == &c)
        return * this;

    delete [] hobby;

    int len = std::strlen(c.name);
    strncpy_s(name, len, c.name, len);
    name[19] = '\0';

    len = std::strlen(c.hobby);
    hobby = new char[len + 1];
    strncpy_s(hobby, len, c.hobby, len);
    hobby[len] = '\0';

    weight = c.weight;
    return * this;
}

void Cow::ShowCow() const
{
    cout << name << ", " << hobby << ", " << weight << endl;  
}
```

> usecow.cpp

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include "cow.h"


  int main()
  {
      Cow Japan;
      Japan.ShowCow();

      Cow America("Aspen", "Swim", 307.45);
      America.ShowCow();

      return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Please add code where you use your `Cow` class.

Comment: Did you check the parameters you passed with what the manual says are needed? In one place you pass only `3` parameters but in another place you pass `4` parameters to `strncpy_s`.

Comment: @Ari0nhh Yes, I add usecow.cpp just now.

Comment: @Galik  I thought strncpy_s() is an overloaded function in those ways.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From `strncpy_s` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx):

> These functions try to copy the first D characters of strSource to
>   strDest, where D is the lesser of count and the length of strSource.
>   If those D characters will fit within strDest (whose size is given as
>   numberOfElements) and still leave room for a null terminator, then
>   those characters are copied and a terminating null is appended;
>   otherwise, strDest[0] is set to the null character and the invalid
>   parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation.

Lets consider your code:

```
int len = std::strlen("no hobby");
hobby = new char[len + 1];
strncpy_s(hobby, len, "no hobby", len);
```

Second argument of `strcpy_s` is a size of buffer in characters. Fourth - number of characters copied. Since you are passing the same `len` variable, `strcpy_s` detects, that buffer has insufficient size (because there should be a space for the trailing \0) and invokes invalid parameters handler. This works correctly:

```
int len = std::strlen("no hobby");
hobby = new char[len + 1];
strncpy_s(hobby, len+1, "no hobby", len);
```

Check other places where you are using `strncpy_s` for this error.
Also it is a good idea to actually read text in the debug assertion windows. In this case error source is pretty straightforward:

[image: debug assertion failed]

Comment: Finally, this project works. It spend me a few days. sigh

Comment: I want to add one question that debug assertion window does not inform users which line where (L"Buffer is too small" && 0) happens.

Comment: @user9418 It does. Press `Retry` button when debugger is attached and it will show you the line with error.

Comment: So far I read code line by line and enter into "Go to definition" by right click. Should I look up other textbooks for more information on strncpy_s()?

Comment: I did what you say. Click retry button. Then the other small window jumps out. It says something like "stop operating" without showing where the line with error. I am using MVS(English version) but my OS is not of English version, So I am not sure what exact meaning of words in that small window.

Comment: Thanks for your time and having patience.

Comment: Note that the final code here offers no additional "safety" over just calling `strcpy`. You already know that the buffer is big enough, because you created it that way.

Comment: One weird thing is that the assertion is also thrown in Release builds. Any idea how to disable that? Release build should have a runtime error thrown instead

Answer (score 1):

```
int len = std::strlen(nm);
strncpy_s(name, len, nm, len);
```

First, the second line should use `len + 1` instead of `len`. And second, it should use `strcpy` instead of `strncpy_s`.

Calculating the length of the source (`strlen(nm)`) doesn't provide any information about the size of the target buffer (`name`). And since there is no information about the size of the target buffer, restricting the number of characters to copy is meaningless. So don't do all that wheel-spinning. Just copy the string:

```
strcpy(name, nm);
```

Comment: Yes, both strcpy() and strncpy() are taught by my textbook. But I am using Visual Studio to write code. Visual Studio says they are unsafe. So I choose strncpy(). Still I would like to say thank you for your time.

Comment: The use of `strncpy_s` in the code example is also "unsafe", in exactly the same way as `strcpy` would be. This is the problem with just about every use of `strncpy` that I've seen on SO: it's used wrong, because whoever wrote the code didn't think enough about the problem that they were trying to solve, and simply chose a function because it was labelled "safe". It's on "safe" if it's used correctly.

Comment: Thanks you. Actually I am taking baby steps in the direction of C++. Your words encourage me a lot.